# Monitor website's http requests

Tags: security, httprequest

I want to know if/how to monitor all of the request made by my website when I loaded through the browser.

The website is very slow, and I suspect there is a hack somewhere. I have done an exhaustive accounting of files and such, but the reason for this recent slowness eludes me.

A few days ago I added a third party service's recommended library for their API service. I want to think this library is friendly, but I am having problems since.

Is there a way to monitor all of the calls made by the website, including any ajax/javascript calls life? If so how?

Comment: Just use your browser’s build-in developer tools (or an extension like f.e. Firebug) … they should have a network panel, where you can watch all requests that are being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in developer tools of Chrome and Firefox should have a network panel that will help.

If you want to see the headers, there's a [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) Firefox extension that might help: